# Opacity(Transparency) and dragging in P5.js/Javascript

Tags: javascript, draggable, p5.js

I need help with changing the opacity(transparency) of the objects and dragging the objects.
I can change the opacity(transparency) but when I do the objects are no longer draggable.

The image below sheds more light on the question

https://ibb.co/2qhX6Jt

The relevant lines for fill colour are lines 54-74

The relevant lines for dragging objects are lines 117-161

You can run and edit the code using P5.js editor,

This is the link to the code.

https://editor.p5js.org/Chigoz/sketches/ulMnSYag4

Comment: You need to add the code to the question. A link to an off-site resource is not sufficient. Links to external resources tend to break and the resource may no longer be available in the future. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You shouldn't use color to detect what you're aiming for since anything obstructing will destroy a fragile balance.

Comment: Hi Olaf, a friend on Processing Foundation forum did the color detection part for me. I do not understand what he actually did that is why I am struggling to fix it. Any other approach is very welcome. Thanks

Comment: I'll shoot my shot at making a hexagon hitbox, but you can always opt-out for a circle hitbox instead if you want a quick and easy solution, or even change the shape into something else.

Comment: Do whatever works, the main thing is that the objects should be transparent and draggable. Thanks

Comment: Do whatever works, the main thing is that the objects should be transparent and draggable. Thanks

Comment: Color was uses because the person didn't want the two objects to combine when they slide past each other. Please do whatever it takes so far it works. Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to implement drag and drop is to do hit-testing for the draggable objects, determine which object is being dragged, and then update the position based on the position of the mouse.

```js
const hexagon = [
  new p5.Vector(50, 0),
  new p5.Vector(25, 43.3),
  new p5.Vector(-25, 43.3),
  new p5.Vector(-50, 0),
  new p5.Vector(-25, -43.3),
  new p5.Vector(25, -43.3)
];

let shapes = [
  { x: 80, y: 80, color: [255, 0, 0, 100], points: hexagon },
  { x: 200, y: 200, color: [0, 255, 0, 100], points: hexagon }
];

let draggingIx;
let draggingOffset;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(300, 300);
}

function draw() {
  background(255);
  for (let shape of shapes) {
    push();
    translate(shape.x, shape.y);
    fill(...shape.color);
    beginShape();
    for (let pt of shape.points) {
      vertex(pt.x, pt.y);
    }
    endShape(CLOSE);
    pop();
  }
}

function mousePressed() {
  // Hit test in reverse order so that the top most element gets hit first
  for (let i = shapes.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    let relativePos = createVector(mouseX - shapes[i].x, mouseY - shapes[i].y);
    if (pointInPoly(shapes[i].points, relativePos)) {
      draggingIx = i;
      draggingOffset = relativePos;
      break;
    }
  }
}

function mouseReleased() {
  draggingIx = draggingOffset = undefined;
}

function mouseDragged() {
  if (draggingIx >= 0) {
    shapes[draggingIx].x = mouseX - draggingOffset.x;
    shapes[draggingIx].y = mouseY - draggingOffset.y;
  }
}

function pointInPoly(verts, pt) {
  let c = false;
  // for each edge of the polygon
  for (let i = 0, j = verts.length - 1; i < verts.length; j = i++) {
    // Compute the slope of the edge
    let slope = (verts[j].y - verts[i].y) / (verts[j].x - verts[i].x);
    
    // If the mouse is positioned within the vertical bounds of the edge
    if (((verts[i].y > pt.y) != (verts[j].y > pt.y)) &&
        // And it is far enough to the right that a horizontal line from the
        // left edge of the screen to the mouse would cross the edge
        (pt.x > (pt.y - verts[i].y) / slope + verts[i].x)) {
      
      // Flip the flag
      c = !c;
    }
  }
  
  return c;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
```

FYI, the point of StackOverflow is to learn how to do something, not to ask people to write arbitrary code for you, which is why I've written some code from scratch to demonstrate how this should be done conceptually.

For more information on how the algorithm for testing if a point is inside a polygon works see [this topic on the Processing.org Discourse forum](https://discourse.processing.org/t/show-country-names-in-a-p5-worldmap/31519).